# Python class with generic and alternative constructor

Tags: python, python-typing

Is there any way how to use `Generic` in class and at the same time define alternative constructor?

My code look like this

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypeVar, TypedDict, Generic, Type

import dataclasses


class Cfg(TypedDict):
    data: int
    foo: str


T = TypeVar("T")


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Foo(Generic[T]):
    
    data: T
    
    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls: Type[Foo[str]], text: str) -> Foo[str]:
        return cls(text[1:-1])

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls: Type[Foo[int]], data: Cfg) -> Foo[int]:
        return cls(data["data"])


a = Foo.from_string("sdffd")
b = Foo.from_config({"data": 1, "foo": "sdfd"})
```

But I get following error from mypy (strict mode is set for mypy)

```
main.py:29: error: Invalid self argument "Type[Foo[Any]]" to attribute function "from_string" with type "Callable[[Type[Foo[str]], str], Foo[str]]"  [misc]
main.py:30: error: Invalid self argument "Type[Foo[Any]]" to attribute function "from_config" with type "Callable[[Type[Foo[int]], Cfg], Foo[int]]"  [misc]
```

Comment: Did you try just `Type[Foo]`, or `Type[Foo[Any]]` in the signatures for the classmethods?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel have checked and that works for me. Is sorta strange that Mypy wouldn't make it that by default

Comment: @KarlKnechtel is there a solution without `Any`, though?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't use this typing stuff, I just read the error message and thought a little bit.

Comment: I think it may require higher-kinded types.

Comment: Anyway, I think the "cleaner" solution is to use `Self = TypeVar("Self", bound="Foo")` then annotate `cls` in the classmethods with `Type[Self]`, or just use [`typing.Self`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/) if you are in a version that supports it

Comment: @KarlKnechtel with `Type[Foo[Any]]` everything work. Thank you. I will open issue on mypy repository if there is possibility to make if somehow cleaner in new verions of mypy.

Comment: @Dolajo if you open an issue could you link to it here, if you don't mind?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga issue is https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/15057